# Collection Cell not calling function in RootViewController (In code application)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

having an issue. I have a collectionView controller and am trying to give "didSelectRowIndex..." a task to call a function for my rootViewController. I am not using MAINSTORYBOARD. Application is written in code.

Collection View Cell Properties:

```
class feedCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UINavigationControllerDelegate  { 

 var messageController: MessageController?
 var specificRoom = [Room]()

 ....

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.messageController?.selectedRoom()
    let roomView = self.specificRoom[indexPath.row]
    self.messageController?.showChatConrollerFoRoom(roomView)

   print("This is cell \(Int)") //<--- PRINTS AND CORRECT INT
  }

 ...

}
```

My rootViewController title : MessageController

```
class MessageController: UITableViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

 ...

 func showChatConrollerFoRoom(roomView: Room){
    let roomLogController = ChatLogController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout())
    roomLogController.roomView = roomView
    navigationController?.pushViewController(roomLogController, animated: true)
    print(12345678) //<---DOES NOT PRINT: FUNCTION NEVER CALLED :(
}

 ...
 }
```

I am new to collectionViews. Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

By default, `UICollectionViewController` is the `delegate` of its `collectionView`. The `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` should be implemented in the `UICollectionViewController` methods, not the within the `cell`. In your case where you used a `UITableViewController` and added a `UICollectionView` yourself, set the delegate to the `MessageController` too and implement `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` there.

And if you make your `cell` the `delegate` of the `collectionView`, know that for every existing cell, the method `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` will be call once when the user selects a `cell`.

Comment: I see. But will each cell still have a unique indexPath? I still a little confused. I understand now that "...viewController" contains delegates for collectionView. But I made collectionViiew a of self with **[lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = { let cv = UICollectionView(), cv.dataSource = Self; cv.delegate = Self return cv}()**

Comment: Yes, in the method `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, the indexPath will be unique for each cell, if you need to access that indexPath from the cell, you can instead add a property IndexPath in your cell that is updated when you dequeue a cell. But if you only need to populate your cell, the indexPath will sufficiently tell you which cell the method is currently trying to populate.